# Value exists multiple times in a range, Need to extract corresponding row values

Tags: excel, vba

I am a learner in Excel and I love learning new things.

A value exists multiple times in a range say B2:Z20.Value does not duplicate in a row i.e it is present only one time in a row in this range. Need to figure out the  value in the corresponding row in column A for every entry of the value.

For e.g. Value "XYZ" exists in column B,D,E,H,J at row 1,4,5,9 and 12 respectively. Need to extract the corresponding values in column A in rows 1,4,5,9 and 12 in different columns.

Comment: Folk offering up their time to help you for free will probably not share your sense of urgency.

Comment: Completely agreed. Apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: May we see what you have tried/researched?

Comment: While searching for this, I found out using the IFERROR with VLOOKUP, but it gives only the 1st value. So if the value is at row 1,4,5,9,12 it gives only the value in the adjacent cell in row 1.  =iferror(vlookup(B2,$B$2:$J$20,2,0),"")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub SearchRange()
    Dim rFound As Range, rng As Range, foundRng As Range
    Dim strName As String
    Dim count As Long, LastRow As Long

    Set rng = Range("B2:Z20")    '->set you range here

    strName = "xyz"    '->enter search string here
    With rng
        Set rFound = .Find(What:=strName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = rFound.Address
            Do
                Debug.Print rFound.Address    '->found cell address
                MsgBox Range("A" & rFound.Row).Value    '-> corresponding Column A value
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing And rFound.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT# 1**
**___________________________________________________________________________**

```
Sub SearchRange()
    Dim rFound As Range, rng As Range, foundRng As Range
    Dim strName As String
    Dim count As Long, LastRow As Long

    Set rng = Range("B2:Z20")    '->set you range here

    For Each cel In Range("AA1:AA5")    '->assuming your search strings are in this range
        strName = cel.Value
        With rng
            Set rFound = .Find(What:=strName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = rFound.Address
                Do
                    Debug.Print rFound.Address    '->found cell address
                    MsgBox rFound.Address & " : " & Range("A" & rFound.Row).Value
                    Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
                Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing And rFound.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If
        End With
    Next cel
End Sub
```

**EDIT# 2**
**___________________________________________________________________________**

```
Sub SearchRange()
    Dim rFound As Range, rng As Range, foundRng As Range
    Dim strName As String
    Dim count As Long, LastRow As Long, rowCntr As Long, colCntr As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim dataWB As Worksheet, resultWB As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set dataWB = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")   '->change to sheet where your data is
    Set resultWB = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")    '->change to sheet where result needs to be displayed

    Set rng = Range("B2:Z20")    '->set you range here

    rowCntr = 1
    For Each cel In dataWB.Range("AA1:AA3")    '->assuming your search strings are in this range
        strName = cel.Value
        With rng
            Set rFound = .Find(What:=strName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            resultWB.Range("A" & rowCntr) = strName    '->enter searched value in result sheet
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                colCntr = 2
                FirstAddress = rFound.Address
                Do
                    '->display corresponding Column A values in result sheet
                    resultWB.Cells(rowCntr, colCntr) = dataWB.Range("A" & rFound.Row).Value
                    Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
                    colCntr = colCntr + 1
                Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing And rFound.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If
        End With
        rowCntr = rowCntr + 1
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: One thing I've wondered about the `.FindNext` code that MS gives as an example:  the `Do....Loop` only fires if `rFound` is something.  The `.FindNext` loops back to the start when it reaches the end of the search range, so surely `rFound` is always something after the first check (unless you're changing the values when found) so the loop conditional would work as: `Loop While rFound.Address <> FirstAddress`.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Mrig. Is there anyway I can run this for mutiple search strings in the same data range. only thing is I would be having large number of unique values for which, I would need to run this.

Comment: @AnkitShukla - How are you planning to provide multiple search strings?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - As you said, checking for first found address will work, unless the values being searched are changed. So `Loop While rFound.Address <> FirstAddress` should work here. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Mrig - Sorry I don't have knowledge on VBA, so do not know how or whether this can be done or not. Post getting the code from you I learnt very basic things about setting up a macro and tried setting it up an a sample data and it works. Issue is I have multiple values for which I need to figure out the respective value in first column. Unable to do that. Thanks for your help anyways. I leaned something new.

Comment: @AnkitShukla - As per the above code, Cells `AA1:AA5` should have multiple search value or you can change the range to fit your requirement.

Comment: @Mrig - Thanks a lot. It works. if you can help me out with this also - Is it possible to get the data from this macro in a tabular form, wherein the particular value in the range gets exported to a new sheet and the corresponding values in column A also get exported with it. for e.g say a value "A" in the range has corresponding values "B",C" and "D" in column A. Can A get exported to A1 in a new sheet and the corresponding values "B","C",D" follow in B1,C1,D1 in the new sheet.  Thanks

Comment: @AnkitShukla - Your explanation here is bit confusing. If you can share sample of your data and desired result it will be easier to understand and we'll not have to work on this to and fro.

Comment: @AnkitShukla - See EDIT# 2.